# Manipulate Red, Green, Blue values for system's screen light

Tags: android, colors, screen, light, led

I'm trying to do a little android demo app for educational purposes, and I've done a little bit of research and can't come across anything that lets me manipulate (with code of course) the Red, Green, or Blue values for the system's screen light. Anyone know if this is possible?

I know know how to manipulate the screen's brightness, but that's not what I'm looking for. Just wanted to know how to manipulate the RGB values for screen's LED light.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The screen has no colour, only what applications paint onto it.  Just make a full screen app, and change it's background colour.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the reply. hmm, in that case you could call it simulating screen's RGB values. I'm trying to do sort of the same thing like those apps that filter blue light from the system screen's light.